# How to set 'Automatic proxy configuration url' by tweaking Firefox preferences using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For testing an application, I've to set 'Automatic proxy configuration url' to something similar to 'http://abc.xyz.com/tester/proxy'

In order to do that, I did following:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(:http => "abc.xyz.com/tester/proxy")

profile.proxy = proxy
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

But this sets 'Manual proxy Configuration' Could you please help me on how to set 'Automatic proxy configuration url'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code sets automatic proxy configuration url:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['network.proxy.type'] = 2
profile['network.proxy.autoconfig_url'] = "http://abc.xyz.com/tester/proxy"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```